# Active Model Serializer Conditional Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

Is it possible to conditionally include a has_one association in an active model serializer on a record-by-record basis?

In my case I need to not return an association called "group" if the group is of the type "invisible".  Here is a snippet from my serializer.

```
class PostFeedSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :thumbnail_photo, :view_count, :ago, :created_by
  has_one :group, serializer: GroupSerializer
```

What I'd like to do is something to the effect of:

```
has_one :group, serializer: GroupTinySerializer unless object.get_group.invisible?
```

Comment: Does Group have a field called `invisible`? And have you defined methods like `invisible?` and `get_group` or that is just an example.

Comment: Yes, get_group and invisible? are existing methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're [using version ~> 0.8.0](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable#attributes), you should be able to put the following in your `PostFeedSerializer`.

```
def include_group?
  !object.get_group.invisible?
end
```

That will conditionally include the `group` object whenever `include_group?` returns true.

Looks like [in future versions](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#attributes), AMS will be moving to `filter` instead of `include_x?` methods.

Comment: where's the documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using a more recent version of Active Model Serializer, the solution would be:

```
  def filter(keys)
    keys.delete :group unless !object.get_group.invisible?
    keys
  end
```

You can also do:

```
has_one :group, serializer: GroupTinySerializer, unless: -> { invisible? }

def invisible?
  object.get_group.invisible?
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid of the newer Active Model Serializer. Too much change.

Comment: I added another way you can also achieve the same result. Don't be afraid of change my small grasshopper.